# Recursively Calling A Class in React-Native

Tags: react-native, recursion

I have a JSON object storing my menus. By default the first menu gets displayed. On Press of any menu item I want to display the menu number defined against "seq". Here is my JSON file **menu.json"

```
{"main":
  [
    {"mid": 0, "menu":
      [
        {"id": "1", "title": "Item-1-0", "kw": "Item-1", "type" : "M", "seq" : 1},
        {"id": "2", "title": "Item-2", "kw": "Item-2", "type" : "M", "seq" : 2},
        {"id": "3", "title": "Item-3", "kw": "Item-3", "type" : "M", "seq" : 3},
        {"id": "4", "title": "Item-4", "kw": "Item-4", "type" : "M", "seq" : 4},
        {"id": "5", "title": "Item-5", "kw": "Item-5", "type" : "M", "seq" : 5},
        {"id": "6", "title": "Item-6", "kw": "Item-6", "type" : "M", "seq" : 6},
        {"id": "7", "title": "Item-7", "kw": "Item-7", "type" : "M", "seq" : 7},
        {"id": "8", "title": "Item-8", "kw": "Item-8", "type" : "M", "seq" : 8}
      ]
    },
    {"mid": 1, "menu":
      [
        {"id": "1", "title": "Item-1-1", "kw": "Item-1", "type" : "M", "seq" : 8},
        {"id": "2", "title": "Item-2", "kw": "Item-2", "type" : "M", "seq" : 9},
        {"id": "3", "title": "Item-3", "kw": "Item-3", "type" : "M", "seq" : 10},
        {"id": "4", "title": "Item-4", "kw": "Item-4", "type" : "M", "seq" : 11},
        {"id": "5", "title": "Item-5", "kw": "Item-5", "type" : "M", "seq" : 12},
        {"id": "6", "title": "Item-6", "kw": "Item-6", "type" : "M", "seq" : 13},
        {"id": "7", "title": "Item-7", "kw": "Item-7", "type" : "M", "seq" : 14},
        {"id": "8", "title": "Item-8", "kw": "Item-8", "type" : "M", "seq" : 15}
      ]
    },
    {"mid": 3, "menu":
      [
        {"id": "1", "title": "Item-1-2", "kw": "Item-1", "type" : "M", "seq" : 16},
        {"id": "2", "title": "Item-2", "kw": "Item-2", "type" : "M", "seq" : 17},
        {"id": "3", "title": "Item-3", "kw": "Item-3", "type" : "M", "seq" : 18},
        {"id": "4", "title": "Item-4", "kw": "Item-4", "type" : "M", "seq" : 19},
        {"id": "5", "title": "Item-5", "kw": "Item-5", "type" : "M", "seq" : 20},
        {"id": "6", "title": "Item-6", "kw": "Item-6", "type" : "M", "seq" : 21},
        {"id": "7", "title": "Item-7", "kw": "Item-7", "type" : "M", "seq" : 22},
        {"id": "8", "title": "Item-8", "kw": "Item-8", "type" : "M", "seq" : 23}
      ]
    },
    {"mid": 4, "menu":
      [
        {"id": "1", "title": "Item-1-3", "kw": "Item-1", "type" : "M", "seq" : 24},
        {"id": "2", "title": "Item-2", "kw": "Item-2", "type" : "M", "seq" : 25},
        {"id": "3", "title": "Item-3", "kw": "Item-3", "type" : "M", "seq" : 26},
        {"id": "4", "title": "Item-4", "kw": "Item-4", "type" : "M", "seq" : 27},
        {"id": "5", "title": "Item-5", "kw": "Item-5", "type" : "M", "seq" : 28},
        {"id": "6", "title": "Item-6", "kw": "Item-6", "type" : "M", "seq" : 29},
        {"id": "7", "title": "Item-7", "kw": "Item-7", "type" : "M", "seq" : 30},
        {"id": "8", "title": "Item-8", "kw": "Item-8", "type" : "M", "seq" : 31}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My **App.js** file is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

import GetMenu from "./fetchmenu.js";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              {<GetMenu/>}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

And the GetMenu class is in this file **fetchmenu.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';

let dataSource = require('./menu.json');
let menuLevel = 0;


export default class GetMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


  render(){
    return(
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
            <FlatList
              data={dataSource.main[menuLevel].menu}
              renderItem={({item}) =>
              (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => actionOnRow(item)}>
                    <Text>{item.title}, {item.kw}, {item.seq}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
            />
          </View>
    );
  }
}

function actionOnRow(item) {
  menuLevel = item.seq;
  alert(item.title + "-" + menuLevel);

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              {<GetMenu/>}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It crashes on render() in **actionOnRow** function

Am I supposed to do it differently instead of recursively calling **actionOnRow** OnPress?

**EDIT**

Once I go past this stage I would like to add a condition in actionOnRow() based on "type". An "M" value will call next menu and some other value like "L" will call an external JSON to display a list of Audios.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: U could store your data source (the one that you pass to flatList) to your state and update your state when menu pressed.

Comment: @AbdumutalAbdusamatov I am totally new to React Native. Can you please provide the exact example code?

Comment: If you could post the revised code in your reply that works then I can accept that as a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first tell you what is your mistake. You are trying to render a component when the menu is pressed. But your are calling render function inside of menu pressed event, but you cannot do it inside of `onPress` event. What you could do here is set some flag indicating whether to render inner menu. In code, it would be like this:

```
//render item of your flatList
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({renderMenu:true,menuItem:item})}>
                <Text>{item.title}, {item.kw}, {item.seq}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
//place where you want to render your menu
{this.state.renderMenu&&actionOnRow(this.state.menuItem)}
```

**Alternatively**

You could store your current menu to your state and update it when menu is pressed. Example code:

```
state={currentMenu:dataSource.main[menuLevel].menu}


<FlatList
          data={this.state.currentMenu}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
          (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({currentMenu:item})}>
                <Text>{item.title}, {item.kw}, {item.seq}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
```

NOTE: I did not test all the code. They are just examples. Let me know if you do not understand something.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have posted the working code as EDIT in your post. I now need to see how pressing back key will take me back to the previous menu item.

Comment: Are u sure you need help for that. It is too easy.

Comment: Yes why not. Started React only a few days back. So every help is useful :)

Comment: Plz watch some tutorials. React’s design patterns are completely different from others.

Comment: I have gone thru a few. Also went thru O'reilly's "Learning Recat Native". But as you said the concepts are totally different. I actually have a published App for Android+iOS that I developed in Cordova/Phonegap with JQuery. I want to rewrite it and thought , React Native might be a good choice for efficiency and better presentation. But as you said the concepts are totally different which I am finding a bit tough to deal with :(

Comment: Is there a way to initialize keyExtractor? In the above code suppose the 1st menu has 10 items. On click if a sub-menu menu is called having 6 items only, it will overwrite the first 6 items and the remaining 4 items of the first menu still remain visible. If I remove the keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id} line then the problem disappears but I get a warning instead. Any solution?

Comment: Solved the issue. If I replace **keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}** with this **keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}** the problem disappears. Although I don't know why!!!